# AWS EMR: how to get the first element out of describe_jobflows() API call result

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, emr, elastic-map-reduce

I cannot figure out how to get the first element of the result from calling one of the `boto emr APIs`:

```
describe_jobflows()
```

i know it returns a `list of jobflows`, but when I'm trying to access it by using :

```
jobflows[0]
```

I got this:

```
ERROR: 'JobFlow' object is not iterable
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right. Problem solved.

I was doing:

```
jobflows += terminatedjobflows[0]
```

that's why it's complaining: object jobflow is not iterable

when I changed it to:

```
jobflow.append(terminatedjobflows[0])
```

it works.